# How to disable input area inside of the input type=file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there's a way to disable the input field and not the "browse" button.

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file">
```

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Using_a_label_element_to_trigger_a_hidden_file_input_element#Using_a_label_element_to_trigger_a_hidden_file_input_element They provide examples on how to use a label with an `input` element to accomplish this.

Comment: while using input type=file, it seems input field is disabled by default user can't type into the textbox.